# SQL: Removing Null Strings

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a two tables "aux1.txt"

```
CREATE TABLE aux1 
  ( 
     "date/time"            DATE, 
     year                   INTEGER, 
     month                  INTEGER, 
     day                    INTEGER, 
     "data quality"         TEXT, 
     "max temp"             REAL, 
     "max temp flag"        TEXT, 
     "min temp"             REAL, 
     "min temp flag"        TEXT, 
     "mean temp"            REAL, 
     "mean temp flag"       TEXT, 
     "heat deg days"        REAL, 
     "heat deg days flag"   TEXT, 
     "cool deg days"        REAL, 
     "cool deg days flag"   TEXT, 
     "total rain"           REAL, 
     "total rain flag"      TEXT, 
     "total snow"           REAL, 
     "total snow flag"      TEXT, 
     "total precip"         REAL, 
     "total precip flag"    TEXT, 
     "snow on grnd"         REAL, 
     "snow on grnd flag"    TEXT, 
     "dir of max gust"      REAL, 
     "dir of max gust flag" TEXT, 
     "spd of max gust"      REAL, 
     "spd of max gust flag" TEXT 
  );
```

with historical weather data and another called "Weather.txt"

```
CREATE TABLE weather 
  ( 
     year           INTEGER, 
     month          INTEGER, 
     day            INTEGER, 
     "max temp"     REAL, 
     "min temp"     REAL, 
     "mean temp"    REAL, 
     "total precip" REAL 
  );
```

with some of those columns. I'd like insert all relevant columns from aux1 in Weather  only if the Max Temp, Min Temp, Mean Temp, Total Precip fields are all not empty. So far I've got:

```
INSERT INTO weather 
SELECT "max temp"     REAL, 
       "min temp"     REAL, 
       "total precip" REAL 
FROM   aux1 
WHERE  "max temp" IS NOT NULL 
       AND "max temp" <> ""
```

and although it seems as though this works for "Max Temp" I'm not sure how to continue doing this syntax wise for all the others. Any direction is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: If `"max temp"` is a `REAL`, how will it ever be `""`?

Answer (score 0):

why not simply:

```
... and "Min Temp" is not null and "Min Temp" <> "" ... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO weather 
SELECT "max temp"     REAL, 
       "min temp"     REAL, 
       "total precip" REAL 
FROM   aux1 
WHERE  "max temp"     IS NOT NULL AND
       "min temp"     IS NOT NULL AND
       "total precip" IS NOT NULL
```

- REAL is not a string, so no reason to check `field <> ""`
- Then just make sure your other fields are also not null